# How can I have an object which can be accessed from different controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with ASP.Net MVC4, I customize my login, this is ok, I would like save this object USER and I can access from differents controllers and differents Areas. I was trying to defined this object as "static" but I can't acces to values of object:

```
if (Servicio.ValidarUsuario())
            {
                string Mensaje = "";
                Models.AdmUsuario oAdmUsuario = new Models.AdmUsuario();
                oAdmUsuario.Au_codusuario = login.UserName;
                Servicio.RetornaEntidad<Models.AdmUsuario>(ref Mensaje, "admsis.adm_usuario", oAdmUsuario.getPk(), oAdmUsuario);
                ***Models.AdmUsuario.UserWeb = oAdmUsuario;***
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.UserName, false);                 
                Session["Modulo"] = null;
                Session["Menu"] = null;
                return RedirectToAction("index", "raMainReclamo", new { area = "Reclamos" });
            }
```

In the model I define:

```
public static AdmUsuario UserWeb;
```

But I can't access to value.
Do you have any idea, how I can to access the values ​​of an object from different controllers in different areas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a way to store the object between requests.  You could put the object in Session Memory and pull it back out.

```
{
    // Other Code
    Session["AdmUsuario"] = oAdmUsuario;
    return RedirectToAction("index", "raMainReclamo", new { area = "Reclamos" });
}
```

Controller in Reclamos Area

```
public class raMainReclamoController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index() {
         var oAdmUsuario = Session["AdmUsuario"] as Models.AdmUsuario;

         // Other Code
    }
}
```

However, the a more standard approach would be to persist the object to a database and then pull it back out.  You could read up on using Entity Framework to access a sql  database.  I like to use RavenDB for storage as it makes saving objects really easy.

** UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS **

**This is just psuedo code as I don't know what you are using to connect to postgres.**

```
{
    // Other Code
    oAdmUsuario = postgresContext.Store(oAdmUsuario);
    postgresContext.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("index", "raMainReclamo", new { area = "Reclamos", id = oAdmnUsuario.Id });
}
```

Controller in Reclamos Area

```
public class raMainReclamoController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int id) {
         var oAdmUsuario = postgresContext.GetById<Models.AdmUsuario>(id);

         // Other Code
    }
```

Comment: Hi Brett, I'm using Postgresql 9.0 Database, and we don't use Entity Framework. It is a good practice to use Sessions? or is there another way to not use Sessions or static variables?

Comment: Raranibar... how long do you need the information to be available for? There are a number of ways to keep objects alive between requests but if this is something you want long term then I would definately persist it to a database.

Comment: Good practice really depends on what you are doing.  Would I store an object in session? No.  Static variables aren't the answer either because once you send a response to the client the value is wiped away.  You need to store the object in Postgres in your first Controller Action, then Pull it back out.  I will edit my answer above with some psuedo code.

Comment: BenjaminPaul, I need the iformation to be available until user close the session

Comment: Brett, I'm trying to understand your answer, what it suggests is user ID send in each call to the controller  and the controller must consult the database to retrieve the user information?

Comment: Brett, I'm using your suggestion, but how I can pass oAdmUsuario.id to others controllers? this code ` return RedirectToAction("index", "raMainReclamo", new { area = "Reclamos", id = oAdmnUsuario.Id });` only passes id for controller raMainReclamo

Comment: you just pass it in the query string /Reclamos/raMainReclamo/Index/345 or /Reclamos/raMainReclamo/Index?id=345.  Any parameter that you specify in your Action Method can be passed in via query string.